# What is the commonly used practice with getters for member fields?

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to learn myself into C++, and as a C#-enthusiast, I always love to use getters and setters. However, I am a bit unsure about the usage in C++.

For my example, I want to create a Todo-List application in C++ with the MVC design pattern. For the entries I have, I want to use a `std::vector` which holds Container classes, containing all the related values to an entry.

Currently, this vector is stored in my model. When a click on my button happens, I am now redirecting the call to a method which determines the call, and calls a method in a EventHandler-class. This call contains needed data out of the UI, and now I also want to obtain my vector out of the model, so I can pass it to the EventHandler as a reference.

Right now, I am using a getter which gets a reference from the member vector like this:

Header:

```
public:
    std::vector<TodoEntry>& getTodoEntries();

private:
    std::vector<TodoEntry> m_todoEntries;
```

Cpp:

```
std::vector<TodoEntry>& UIModel::getTodoEntries()
{
    return m_todoEntries;
}
```

Is this the correct way of doing this in C++? I am not quite sure, so I'd rather ask here.

Comment: Your `m_todoEntries` is effectively `public` since anyone can do anything with it through `getTodoEntries`. Consider making `m_todoEntries` `public` and remove `getTodoEntries` to model the situation more precisely and with less code. That said, the way you did it is common and accepted. But of course that is *primarily opinion based*.

Comment: Could you clarify your question?

Comment: This effectively breaks encapsulation. Do you _really_ need to let the client alter `m_todoEntries` at will? Consider writing `const std::vector<TodoEntry>& getTodoEntries() const` instead.

Comment: One thing you *will* discover in C++ is that C++ programmers are extremely diverse about coding standards and patterns. There is no general "common practice".

Comment: @nwp Yes, that is indeed true, I do break encapsulation here, and I could just set it to public, but it's rather more of a personal issue for me, I want to learn about C++ references and value passing, so I try to take most of the hurdles.

Comment: @nwp I understand your point and can't argue against it. However, one argument for still wrapping the private data member with a public _setter_ and _getter_ is that it allows the class to still manage the state of the data member. For example, a private `std::string` data member where there is a class invariant that it should never be an empty string (i.e., the class can manage the invariant and it's not a responsibility put on the users of the class). Of course that implies making the `getter` const correct as well.

Comment: @JamesAdkison I agree that the function version is more powerful since it can check pre- and post conditions and can also make a copy of `m_todoEntries` and return a reference to it. However, you pay for it with developer time and chances are you will never use those features. I would make `m_todoEntries` `public` for now and delay writing `getTodoEntries` until required. When you add the getter the compiler will tell you exactly where you need to change your code, so that is not an issue. In case you write a library and it is an issue use a *PIMPL* and some sort of `array_view`.

Comment: *I always love to use getters and setters.* - they do not deserve your love.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using getters and setters is usual in C++ and allows, in many cases, to provide a stable interface while the implementation can change.

Returning a reference in a getter can make sense in some cases but usually, you should prefer returning by copy. The reason is that you usually expect getters to be `const` methods (working on `const` objects and guaranteeing that the object is not modified).

However, if you return a non-const reference or a pointer to your internals, it means the caller can then modify your object even if the getter is a `const` method. (Even with a `const` reference, the caller can `const_cast` it but he's breaking the type system so you can hold him responsible for the consequences). Moreover, the object will usually own the object pointed by the reference or pointer returned and the caller has to be careful about its lifetime to avoid dangling pointers.

Of course, in terms of performances, returning a potentially big `vector` of potentially big objects can be very expansive: it will copy the `vector`. The copy constructor of the `vector` will copy all the `TodoEntry` objects it contains. What it will do exactly depends on the copy constructor of `TodoEntry`, but usually it will copy everything it contains (a.k.a deep copy).

So this may well be a case for returning a reference in the end. Maybe you can return a `const` reference here ? This would be my preference here, with this signature:

```
const std::vector<TodoEntry>& getTodoEntries() const;
```

As quite often, I advise Scott Meyer's book *[Effective C++](https://books.google.fr/books?id=U7lTySXdFk0C&lpg=PT472&ots=nO6Qy5v6lc)* that deals with this in item 28: *Avoid returning "handles" to object internals*.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Then a reference is most likely my go to, as I want to edit that certain vector, and not a copy of it

Comment: If you want to edit it, then a reference (non const) will do what you want. But it means you cannot change the internal container from a vector to a list so your vector basically became public (i.e you don't gain anything anymore to have a getter). In this case, I would make the member public and not use a getter (but this is personal preference, some other developers may still prefer a getter that allows to add some operations later: check invariants, log something etc ...)

Answer (score 1):

Pure setters/getters are not giving you anything, just make for more typing. They also make indirect access to the class members (through pointer) harder, and you do get nothing in return. Do not do pure setters/getters.

Getters have their due when they are **not** paired with setters (the underlying data member is `const` and set only once during initialization or a derived value from the class state), or provide certain invariant checking.

Setters can be used when they provide invariant checking as well. And I never buy the argument "yes, no invariant checking now, but I might add it later". When you add it, than you introduce setters. I have seen a codebase of 10+ years old, where setters were introduced under this pretence, and never moved to invariant checking.

Comment: When your code is distributed, encapsulation provides you more flexibility to change your implementation. Of course, it's not always useful but in many cases it's much more future proof

Comment: @ColinPitrat, it's a myth that you can maintain backward compatibility of your library for years to come.

Comment: This is my daily job and I can assure you some technics help